# elasticsearch: count appearance of terms aggregation on other fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to count how many times, unique values (result of terms aggragation) have appeared in other fields in the same query. Let's say:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_products": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "products.name.keyword",
        "min_doc_count": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to count, how many time each of the `key`s returned in the bucket, appeared in another field.
My ideal output is:

```
  "aggregations": {
    "product_stat": {
      "key": "<product_name>"
      "sold": "<#>" #I want to know how many times the key is appeared in another field like sold
      "bought": "<#>"
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elasticsearch [cannot do `terms` aggregations over multiple fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation). In short, if they would, aggregations would not be blazing fast.

As documentation suggests, there are two options:

- use [script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) terms aggregation (with performance penalty),
- change how the documents are indexed so a normal `terms` aggregation can be used.

Depending on the structure of your data and your use-cases, you might get by with a complex aggregation + some processing on the client side. This can be done with [sub aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations.html#_structuring_aggregations) like [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-order), for example.

Hope that helps!